# I want too add a !add command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im trying to add !add command to my ticket bot using discord py.

the command would add a discord member to the channel and give them perms to send messages and see the channel history

Any help would be greatly appreciated

ive tried this

```
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def add(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    guild = ctx.message.guild

    overwrites = {
    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
    member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
    }

    category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name="Alliances")
```

Comment: I fail to see how this is what you've tried. All this does is check if a channel exists, it doesn't actually try to give someone permissions

Comment: i entered the wrong code:

This is the correct code:

```@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def add(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    guild = ctx.message.guild

    overwrites = {
    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
    member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
    }

    category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name="Alliances")
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post with the correct code, do not use comments for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

```
    category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name = "enter Category")

    channel = await guild.create_text_channel(
               f'{ctx.author.name}', category = category)

    await channel.set_permissions(guild.default_role, view_channel = False)
    await channel.set_permissions(user, view_channel = True)

    await channel.send(user.mention)
    await channel.send("Ticket Opened !")
```

**Something Like This**